# routingError returns NETWORK_COMMUNICATION

Tags: here-api

getting NETWORK_COMMUNICATION when calling coreRouter.calculateRoute

not sure what url is't trying to reach ,
so can not test connection issue.

```
coreRouter.calculateRoute(routePlan, new CoreRouter.Listener() {
@Override
public void onCalculateRouteFinished(List<RouteResult> list,
                                     RoutingError routingError) {
```

the routingError returns NETWORK_COMMUNICATION .

Using phone to test and am connected to the wifi network and can view webpages via the chrome browser

Comment: Can you please share some more information about the API with release and also some code for reproducing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

NETWORK_COMMUNICATION with SDK usually indicates a connectivity issue with HERE Servers, the connectivity issue could occur

- if there are issues accessing HERE Servers by the SDK, make sure all *here.com are whitelisting if you device is using any proxy or
- The map data on the device is very old and it is not being maintained anymore and make sure the device map is updated using the corresponding method in SDK `MapLoader.checkForMapDataUpdate()` and `MapLoader.performMapDataUpdate()`